# Publish asp.net mvc missing images

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a networkdrive z: where I publish my asp.net mvc project to, and when I do some images from my Content/Images directory doesnt get published. Why is that? Every time I have to copy the imagesfolder manually to make sure. I have set it so it deletes all on the target before it publishes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- In the solution explorer (ctrl+w,s)
  select an image that is not copied
  to the publish folder.
- Check the
  properties panel (ctrl+w,p) and make
  sure the image has the "Build Action" property
  set to "Content".

From your description I assume that now it is set to "None".

Answer (score 0):

Are the images part of the project, or do they just sit in the folder on disk? If they are not part of the project, they won't be published.

Comment: they were copied into the folder, and included into the project with "show all" + "include in project"